# SQL Preferred column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table that keeps details about people, for example:

- Name
- Address
- WorkEmail
- HomeEmail
- Preferred Email ('WorkEmail' or 'HomeEmail')

I want to select their preferred email only. Is there a neat way to do this using SQL? or will I just need to do this after I pull out the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple case statement should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    CASE WHEN PreferredEmail = 'WorkEmail' THEN WorkEmail ELSE HomeEmail END AS Email
FROM
    MyTable
```

Comment: Awesome! did the trick nicely. Cheers! I'm sorta still a bit of a noob when it comes to SQL

Comment: You're welcome! You could mark the answer as correct too... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
(Select WorkEmail from MyTable where preferredEmail = 'WorkEmail') 
 Union
(Select HomeEmail from MyTable where preferredEmail = 'HomeEmail')
```

Answer (score 2):

select IF(PreferredEmail = 'WorkEmail', WorkEmail, HomeEmail) AS Email

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a list of more than one email?  If you are collecting multiple email address and you may at sometime want to collect more than one you could always create a secondary table that would associate the user with all of their possible email addresses and have a second third column that could be a flag to signify the Primary email.

Main Table

```
- UID
- Name
- Address
```

Email table

```
- UID
- Email address
- Primary
```

Then you could just do a query for where Primary is flagged and join to the other on the Unique ID.